# Confusing Challenging on Quantum theory

Tags: voltage

Current= The rate at which electron flows. (in other words Speed of flow)
Voltage= Energy carried individual Electrons.( This charged energy over electrons makes to push the neighbour electrons. Thts how electron flow starts)

Considering pure Capacitive oad.
Current leads by 90'.

Does it mean Current start flowing when voltage is Zero.?

Comment: For real or theoretical devices? Real devices all have inductance and resistance in the leads ..

Comment: Besides that the question is totally unclear, it looks like you are talking about Quantum theory using terms which are incompatible with it.

Comment: I consider current to be more like volume of flow than speed of flow, and the energy carried by the electrons as charge (coulombs), not voltage.

Comment: The title "Quantum Theory" is incorrect. However, that aside, as mentioned 'current' is more so the volume. Electrons travel at some speed in a medium, something you can't easily change without changing the medium. Thus, you increase the current by increasing the total quantity of electrons traveling at one time, the volume.

Comment: Voltage is the potential difference between these portions of space. If everything is at the same potential, your voltage is 0, no work can be done. If one spot has more electrons than another (which carry charge denoted in Coulombs), there is some voltage and work can be done.

Comment: The concept of phase to describe the flow of current and voltage in a capacitor only applies to the steady state with sinusoidal voltages and currents.  For transients and other waveforms, the defining equation relating current to the derivative of voltage must be applied. In any event,it is not clear what you are asking. You need to provide a better description of the situation you are asking about.

Comment: The 90 degree thing is only for AC, DC is considered blocked by a pure capacitor.

Comment: @Barry, I agree. Though sometimes the confusion about a topic makes it hard to formulate a clear question... Hopefully our scattershot replies are enough to trigger some clarity ;-)

Comment: If the formula for the shape of an egg is 2304((5-x)²+y²) - (3x²+3y²-40x+44)²=0, then how many do I need to bake a cake?

Comment: @Andyaka - Forty Two

Answer (score 4):

> Current= The rate at which electron flows. (in other words Speed of flow)

Not speed of flow. Quantity of flow. \$ I = \frac {Q}{t} \$ where *I* is current, *Q* is charge and *t* is time.

> Voltage= Energy carried individual Electrons.( This charged energy over electrons makes to push the neighbour electrons. Thts how electron flow starts) (sic)

Voltage is the potential difference between two points in a circuit. The definition is "One volt is defined as the difference in electric potential between two points of a conducting wire when an electric current of one ampere dissipates one watt of power between those points." Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt#Definition).

> Considering pure Capacitive oad (sic). Current leads by 90'.
>   Does it mean Current start flowing when voltage is Zero.? (sic)

No. It means that maximum rate of change of voltage is at peak current. At maximum voltage current is zero. As @Barry said in the comments, this is true in the steady state for sinusoidal voltages and currents.

[image]

*Figure 1. Source: [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-4/ac-capacitor-circuits/).*